# Typed property Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::$container must not be accessed before initialization error

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, mockery

I'm encountering an error in my Symfony application related to accessing the $container property of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
 
Error: Typed property Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::$container must not be accessed before initialization

D:\Development\omegofleet\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Controller\AbstractController.php:343
D:\Development\omegofleet\src\Controller\UserController.php:203
D:\Development\omegofleet\tests\UserTest.php:185
```

Here's an example of my controller class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Company;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private UserRepository $userRepository;
    private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UserRepository $userRepository, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    #[Route('/api/users/{id}', name: 'user_delete', methods: ['DELETE'])]
    public function delete(User $user): Response
    {
        $currentUser = $this->getUser();

        if (!$currentUser) {
            return $this->json(['error' => 'User not authenticated'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        // Load user's role
        $userRole = $this->getUserRole($currentUser->getUsername());

        if (!in_array($userRole, ['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'])) {
            return $this->json(['error' => 'Access denied'], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        }
```

And here's part of my usertest class:

```
#[AllowDynamicProperties] class UserTest extends WebTestCase
{

    protected function setUp(): void
    {

        parent::setUp(); // Ensure parent setUp method is called


        $this->entityManagerMock = Mockery::mock(EntityManagerInterface::class);
        $this->userRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock(UserRepository::class);
        $this->tokenStorageMock = Mockery::mock(TokenStorageInterface::class); // Add this line

    }
    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testLoginSuccessful()
    {
        $mockRequest = Mockery::mock(Request::class);
        $mockRequest->allows('getContent')->andReturns(json_encode(['name' => 'john.doe']));


        $mockUser = $this->createMockUser('john.doe', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN');


        $mockUserRepository = Mockery::mock(UserRepository::class);
        $mockUserRepository->allows('findOneBy')->with(['name' => 'john.doe'])->andReturns($mockUser);
        $this->entityManagerMock
            ->allows('getRepository')
            ->with(User::class)
            ->andReturns($mockUserRepository);

        $mockEntityManager = Mockery::mock(EntityManagerInterface::class);
        $mockEntityManager->allows('getRepository')->with(User::class)->andReturns($mockUserRepository);

        // Create mock UserController with required dependencies
        $mockController = Mockery::mock(UserController::class, [$this->entityManagerMock, $this->userRepositoryMock, $this->tokenStorageMock]) // Pass $this->tokenStorageMock here
        ->makePartial(); // Allow calling actual `generateToken`
//        $mockController->allows('generateToken')->with('john.doe')->andReturns('test_token');

        // Call the login method
        $response = $mockController->login($mockRequest);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(JsonResponse::class, $response);
        $responseData = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('token', $responseData);
        $this->assertIsString($responseData['token']);

        // Decode and verify the JWT token
                $secretKey = $_ENV['JWT_SECRET'];
        $decodedToken = JWT::decode($responseData['token'], new Key($secretKey, 'HS256'));
        $this->assertEquals('john.doe', $decodedToken->name);

// Retrieve the role from the UserRepository
        $userRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock(UserRepository::class);
        $userRepositoryMock->allows('loadUserByRole')->with('john.doe')->andReturn('ROLE_USER_ADMIN');

// Mock the EntityManagerInterface
        $mockEntityManager = Mockery::mock(EntityManagerInterface::class);
        $mockEntityManager->allows('getRepository')->with(User::class)->andReturn($userRepositoryMock);

// Call the login method
        $response = $mockController->login($mockRequest);

// Assert the response
        $this->assertInstanceOf(JsonResponse::class, $response);
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
        return $response;

    }
  protected function createMockUser(string $name, string $role): User
    {
        $mockUser = new User();

        $mockUser->setName($name);
        $mockUser->setId(1);
        $mockUser->setRole($role);
        return $mockUser;
    }
    public function testDeleteAsSuperAdmin(): void
    {
        // Dummy login process
        $loginResponse = $this->testLoginSuccessful();
        $token = json_decode($loginResponse->getContent(), true)['token'];

        // Create a user using the createMockUser method
        $user = $this->createMockUser('Test User', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN');
        $user->setId(1);

        $this->entityManagerMock
            ->allows('getRepository')
            ->with(User::class)
            ->andReturns($this->userRepositoryMock);
        // Create a DELETE request to delete the user
        $request = Request::create('/api/users/' . $user->getId(), 'DELETE');
        $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token);

        // Mock EntityManager to remove the user
        $this->entityManagerMock->allows('remove')->with($user);
        $this->entityManagerMock->allows('flush');

        // Create an instance of UserController with mocked dependencies
        $controller = new UserController($this->entityManagerMock, $this->userRepositoryMock, $this->tokenStorageMock);

        // Expectation on the userRepositoryMock should be set before calling the delete method
        $this->userRepositoryMock
            ->allows('find')
            ->with($user->getId())
            ->andReturns($user);

        // Call the delete method with the fetched user object
        $response = $controller->delete($user);

        // Assert the response status code and content
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString('{"message": "User deleted"}', $response->getContent());
    }

    protected function generateDummyToken(string $username): string
    {
        // Generate a dummy JWT token for testing purposes
        $payload = [
            'name' => $username,
            'exp' => time() + 3600 // Token expiration time (1 hour)
        ];
        $secretKey = 'dummy_secret_key'; // Replace with your actual secret key
        return JWT::encode($payload, $secretKey, 'HS256');
    }
```

And here is the line from AbstractController :

```
 protected function getUser(): ?UserInterface
    {
        if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
            throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application. Try running "composer require symfony/security-bundle".');
        }
```

and here is the service.yml :

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:
  # default configuration for services in *this* file
  _defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

  # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
  # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
  App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
      - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
      - '../src/Entity/'
      - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

Despite this setup, I'm still encountering the error. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is your controller registered as a service?

Comment: yes it is registered. I edited my question and shared the service.yml.

Comment: What is `D:\Development\omegofleet\tests\UserTest.php:185`?  The UserTest Class you gave us has only 78 lines.

Comment: I have added the rest of its code.

Comment: Testing controller is a bit unusual. The problem is that there is a AbstractController::setContainer method which needs to be called before using the methods that use the container such as getUser can be called. Which means mocking the container and mocking assorted services in it. I know 100% test coverage is a thing but might not be worth it for controllers.

Comment: In the interview test its required that all the methods must be tested. how can an endpoint be tested if Testing controller is Unusual!!!?

Comment: Controller generally just pull data from the request and send it to another service for testing. The service is what would be unit testing. Controllers are sometimes integration tested just to verify the routes and such exist. Perhaps part of the interview test is to know when unit testing is not the best approach? In any event the error comes from the container not being set.

Comment: You could also try to argue that while technically controller action methods are public, they are basically private in the sense that only the framework would ever call them. Might need to do quite a bit of hand waving. Depends on what the tester is looking for.

Comment: Wait a second. Is this really a serious question? I just noticed that your UserTest extends WebTestCase.  That means it is an integration test. You don't mock stuff in integration testing. Nor would you ever mock the class being tested. Stop whatever you are doing and read the Symfony chapter on testing.